# Micronaut installing using sdkman, accession micronaut command line permission denied

Tags: macos, permission-denied

Did sdkman install micronaut
called mn command and got the error as
$ mn
-bash: /Users/xxxxxx/.sdkman/candidates/micronaut/current/bin/mn: Permission denied..
how to fix this issue ?

This is happening in MAC.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the user running that command has no execution permission on that file.

Try running `sudo chmod 755 /Users/xxxxxx/.sdkman/candidates/micronaut/current/bin/mn`